# Calculadora javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo que hacer una calculadora gráfica en Javascript, y el problema que tengo es que necesito hacer que al pulsar cada botón de operación se imprima en el texto el resultado entre los números anteriores. 
Se me ha ocurrido hacerlo con un contador booleano para que solo el primer click en la operación no imprima el resultado. Funciona solo la primera vez, ya que luego se empiezan a concatenar los siguientes números que introduzco con el resultado anterior. 
 ¿Hay alguna forma más sencilla de hacerlo?

```
<fieldset>
            <legend>Codigo</legend>
            <div id="calculadora">
                <div id="texto"></div>
                <button id="ce">CE</button>
                <button id="c">C</button>
                <button id="d">D</button>
                <button id="dividir">÷</button>
                <button id="siete">7</button>
                <button id="ocho">8</button>
                <button id="nueve">9</button>
                <button id="multiplicar">x</button>
                <button id="cuatro">4</button>
                <button id="cinco">5</button>
                <button id="seis">6</button>
                <button id="resta">-</button>
                <button id="uno">1</button>
                <button id="dos">2</button>
                <button id="tres">3</button>
                <button id="suma">+</button>
                <button id="posneg">+-</button>
                <button id="cero">0</button>
                <button id="coma">,</button>
                <button id="igual">=</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
```

Javascript

```
var sacarElemento = document.getElementById.bind(document);
var texto = sacarElemento('texto');
var numero;
var cont = true;

sacarElemento('calculadora').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
var target = event.target;

if (target && target.matches('button')) {
    if (!isNaN(target.textContent)) {
        texto.textContent = texto.textContent + target.textContent;
    } else if (target.textContent == "+") {
        if (!cont) {
            texto.textContent = parseFloat(numero) + parseFloat(texto.textContent);
        } else {
            numero = texto.textContent;
            texto.textContent = "";
        }
        cont = false;
    }
 }
```

})

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML.

Comment: Ya está editado con el HTML

Answer (score 3):

Creo que vas bien.  Te faltaba implementar el `=` y el `CE`.  No necesitas el valor booleano.

```js
var sacarElemento = document.getElementById.bind(document);
var texto = sacarElemento('texto');
var numero;
var cont = true;
var result = document.getElementById('result');

sacarElemento('calculadora').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
var target = event.target;

if (target && target.matches('button')) {
    if (!isNaN(target.textContent)) {
        texto.textContent = texto.textContent + target.textContent;
    } else if (target.textContent == "+") {
        if (!cont) {            
            result.textContent = parseFloat(numero) + parseFloat(texto.textContent);
            numero = result.textContent;
            texto.textContent = "";            
        } else {            
            numero = texto.textContent;            
            texto.textContent = "";
            cont = false;
        }
        
    }
 }
})
```

```css
button {
 width: 35px;
 }
```

```html
<fieldset>
            <legend>Codigo</legend>
            <div id="calculadora">
                <div id="result"></div>
                <div id="texto"></div>
                <div>
                <button id="ce">CE</button>
                <button id="c">C</button>
                <button id="d">D</button>
                <button id="dividir">÷</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                <button id="siete">7</button>
                <button id="ocho">8</button>
                <button id="nueve">9</button>
                <button id="multiplicar">x</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                <button id="cuatro">4</button>
                <button id="cinco">5</button>
                <button id="seis">6</button>
                <button id="resta">-</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                <button id="uno">1</button>
                <button id="dos">2</button>
                <button id="tres">3</button>
                <button id="suma">+</button>
                
                </div>
                <div>
                <button id="posneg">+-</button>
                <button id="cero">0</button>
                <button id="coma">,</button>
                <button id="igual">=</button>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </fieldset>
```

Comment: Tu código está bien si el resultado se imprime solo con el "=", lo que me pide el ejercicio es que cada vez que pulses un botón de operación te saque el resultado de los números anteriores con el resultado que ya se tiene, como la calculadora de W10

Comment: En ese caso necesitas otro div para desplegar el resultado.  Ya edite mi respuesta.

Comment: Me he permitido "adornar" un poco el HTML para que se vea el teclado más bonito, espero que no te importe @alanfcm

Comment: Ahora sí funciona, muchas gracias. Lo único que faltaría es poder concatenar varios tipos de operaciones, porque con ese código puedes hacer solo un tipo de operacion seguida, ya que al cambiar a otro no funciona bien